# Undefined index when GET xml from php

Tags: javascript, html, xml, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I have an pre-done php file thats help me read from an xml file.
The problem is when im calling it from the html file ill get the undefined index.

I know Im missing something, but cant seem to know how to double? implement them in the get string.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","prod.php?category=1"+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

and the error message is pointing om row 7 in my PHP file where it says

```
$products = $_GET['products'];
```

If i change my GET file from category=1 to prodicts=1 i get the error in row 6 where the

```
$category = $_GET['category']; variable is.
```

Any ideas ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if `$_GET['products']` and `$_GET['category']` even exist. Try:

```
if(isset($_GET['products'])){
    $products = $_GET['products'];
}
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
    $category = $_GET['category'];
}
```

It's saying that `$products` or `$category` are undefined.

Comment: This worked, when i changed the PHP file, but I'm not supposed to change that file.
Is there another way i can manage the problem from the index file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to monitor the concrete HTTP request that you send to the server. If:

- the query-part contains the variable, the error is wrong and you must have made something wrong in the PHP or webserver configuration.
- the query-part does not contain those variables, the error messages are correct. You then might want to check why those variables are not part of the request.